# Office Excel 2013 - Keyboard shortcut for Unhiding Column Ctrl + Shift + )

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Office Excel 2013 - Keyboard shortcut for Unhiding Column is not working, however at the same time QAT - icon shortcut works.

Answer (score 1):

That keyboard shortcut is assigned to a system operation in Vista and above. See [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967893)

You'll need to change that before it will work for excel -

> Remove the shortcut assignment to make the application work as
>   expected. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> ```
> Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
> Double-click Regional and Language Options.
> Click Keyboards and Languages, and then click Change keyboards.
> Click Advanced Key Settings, and select Between input languages.
> Click change Key Sequence.
> For Switch Keyboard Layout, select Not Assigned.
> Click OK to close each dialog box.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

The keyboard shortcut for unhiding columns is: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd>

(The other one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd> is for hiding.)